# Connecting a UIButton to an IBOutlet and IBAction in code

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction, iboutlet

I have this is viewDidLoad:

```
// Set up register button
UIButton *registerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[registerButton setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
registerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.screenWidth / 2.0, 100.0);
```

and this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
}
```

I also have this in my .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *registerButton;
```

How do I connect IBOutlets and IBActions to buttons I create in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a target to the button like this:

`[registerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: so we don't need an IBOutlet?

Comment: No because you don't use the Interface Builder - or do I understand that wrong?

Comment: @chris: are you not using xib or storyboard?

Comment: Not always. You can create the xib and add (and create) all UI elements per code. (Don't forget to add them to the view).

Comment: I'm doing it all via code, just so I can get better with the api (and if I would I'm using storyboards)

Comment: The @IBOutlet will enable the IB to "find" the outlet, it's only a marker.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *registerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            registerButton.frame=CGRectMake(150, 10, 150,25);
            registerButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

            [registerButton setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [registerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [view.contentView addSubview:registerButton];
```

Try this. I think this will work for you.