# Handle NSButton click programmatically

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I'm attempting to make a subclassed `NSButton` handle a click event with no luck.

To this point I have been customizing the `drawRect` functions in my views to get custom looks and drawing these views programmatically.  To this end, I have essentially orphaned my usage of the Interface builder (simply to avoid its sheer complexity).

Is there a way for me to assign a click (or mouseDown in this scenario) handler programmatically, this doesn't seem to be working

```
class MainButton: NSButton {

    override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent!) {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Title"
        alert.runModal()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        let circle : NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(
            roundedRect: rect, xRadius: rect.size.width / 2,
            yRadius: rect.size.height / 2
        )

        circle.lineWidth = 2

        NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.2, alpha: 1).setStroke()
        circle.stroke()
    }
}
```

Here is [a full gist of the app for context if needed](https://gist.github.com/jondavidjohn/0185612b74b9f674fdf0).

Comment: have you tried: `[buttonInstance addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` and add the `buttonPressed:` method. See [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18439452/451475).

Comment: Subclassing buttons is problematic due to the fact it is a class cluster. Not that it can't be done.

Comment: @Zaph Thanks, but I'm really uncertain where that goes, and then where to add the buttonPressed function.  also, using Swift not Obj-C.

Comment: Adding a new platform is always difficult but studying the documentation really is necessary. You have chosen to use Swift and that adds to the difficulties since it is broken and the error messages are currently just horrible. Further the APIs are in Objective-C making things even more difficult.